# Date not being saved to mySQL datebase with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I've got a jquery datepicker

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showOn: 'focus',changeMonth: true,
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    changeYear: true,

});
});
```

with some validation

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        "date" => 'required|date',
    ]);
```

and some conversion for the date to pass through to the database

```
    $date = $request->input('date');
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$date);
    $date3 = $date2->format("Y-d-m");
```

If I dd($date3) at this point, with a chosen date, I get something like this

```
"2016-29-09"
```

All well and good, mysql appears to save in a y-d-m format.

Now when I go to pass it through

```
    Message::where('id', $messageId)->update([
        'updated_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'subject' => 'Status: Price quote delivered.',  
        'quoted' => 1,
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'estimated_date'  => $date3,            
    ]);
```

everything gets passed to the database except the date. The date just stays at 0000-00-00 in the database.

Help?

Comment: test with hardcoded value `'estimated_date'  => '2016-09-26',` not 2016-26-09

Comment: You have to pass date with `Y-m-d` format.

Comment: $date3 = $date2->format("Y-m-d");

Comment: if your problem has been resolved, than choose the best answer and mark as accepted, this will to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are saving date as `YEAR-DAY-MONTH` and the correct format for `DATE` is `YEAR-MONTH-DAY`.

Also note that value of `$date3` is "2016-29-09", this will insert value in your table as "0000-00-00" due to invalid value of Month and correct range of Month is **(1-12)** for data type `DATE`.

**Solution:**

You need to change the date format (YEAR-MONTH-DAY) as per your Data type of column.

```
$date3 = $date2->format("Y-m-d"); // something like 2016-09-26
```

*You can also follow the reference: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html*

Answer (score 2):

Bro, check this line:

**All well and good, mysql appears to save in a y-d-m format.
Now when I go to pass it through**

Mysql default format is

> Y-m-d

not

> y-d-m

Change the format and try again.

Comment: then why in the hell do entries come out like "2016-09-28" when viewing the database??

Oh well. I don't even care. It works now. Thanks

Comment: Bro, "2016-09-28" is Y-m-d format, 28 is not month. So just keep your eyes open

Comment: Either I'm going crazy or I need sleep

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do with this:

From:

`$date3 = $date2->format("Y-d-m");`

To:

`$date3 = $date2->format("Y-m-d");`

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using a javascript date object, then it is validated in Laravel, why don't you use Carbon? If the date is validated, then instead of reinventing the wheel, just let Carbon and Laravel handle all the date work:

```
$date = new \Carbon\Carbon($request->input('date'));

Message::where('id', $messageId)->update([
    'updated_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    'subject' => 'Status: Price quote delivered.',  
    'quoted' => 1,
    'price' => $request->input('price'),
    'estimated_date'  => $date,            
]);
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/composer.json it's still there