# why the date information cannot be saved into mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My code is in PHP Laravel. And I tried to create a table in font-end which allow user to select my_date information from the drop-down calendar. Then, in back-end, I tied to save the table information into database via migration. But **why the date information cannot be saved into mySQL database?**

[image]

In `config/database.php` I already have

```
'strict' => false,
```

In **index.blade.php** file

```
<input id="my_date" type="text"
       class=...
       name="record[my_date]"
       value="{{isset($project)&&isset($project->my_date)?$project->my_date->format('Y-m-d'):null}}"
       placeholder="{{resolve('translate')->getWord('My Date')}}"
 >
```

In **migration**

`$table->dateTime('my_date');`

I saw from this pots --> [Date not being saved to mySQL datebase with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695974/date-not-being-saved-to-mysql-datebase-with-laravel)

And I tried --> I didn't get any error. Just when I delete & `php artisan migrate`  & fill the font-end table again, there is still no date information being saved.

```
$table->dateTime('my_date')->format("Y-d-m");
```

I saw from this post --> [After upgrade to laravel 5.3 error invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946607/after-upgrade-to-laravel-5-3-error-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datet)

And I tried --> no error, but still, no date information being saved.

```
$table->dateTime('pcmm_shipment_date')->default(NOW());
```

I also tried --> no error, but still, no date information being saved.

```
$table->datetime('expires_at')->nullable($value = true);
```

```
public function storeMyData(Request $request)
    {

        //validate
        $validator = Validator::make($request['record'],
            [
                'project_id' => 'required',
                'my_date' => 'required',
            ]
        );
        ...  
    }
```

Comment: `NOT working` is not a very helpful description of an issue. Not working HOW? Do you get errors?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you! I didn't get any error. Just when I delete & ```php artisan migrate```  & fill the font-end table again, there is still no date information being saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useCurrent` like so:

`$table->timestamp('my_date')->useCurrent();`

From the Laravel file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/ColumnDefinition.php` it defines it as:

> Set the TIMESTAMP column to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value

Comment: Thank you! I just tried. No error, but there is still no date being saved. Would you mind let me know a little bit more? Expect from that file under migration, is there any other file I need to change as well?

Comment: @Flora could you post your controller code where you are trying to save your record to the db please?

Comment: I update the controller code. It's wired, I also saved information for drop-down list & string etc using the same controller. And all other information are saved.

Comment: @Flora in your controller, can you `dd` the value of the input please? It might be that you are setting the value there which is overriding the default value when inserting into your db

Comment: @Flora can you please also edit your question with the code from your controller please?